# CentOS new repositories install

Tags: centos, rpm, repository, dependencies

I am trying to install a package but this package needs to some dependencies. You can see installation output at below.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    jack-audio-connection-kit = 1.9.9.5-6.el7 is needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-devel-1.9.9.5-6.el7.x86_64
    libjack.so.0()(64bit) is needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-devel-1.9.9.5-6.el7.x86_64
    libjacknet.so.0()(64bit) is needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-devel-1.9.9.5-6.el7.x86_64
    libjackserver.so.0()(64bit) is needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-devel-1.9.9.5-6.el7.x86_64
```

I searched jack-audio-connection-kit package after I got this log. I found [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.9.5-6.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) some instructions for jack-audio-connection-kit package.

I looked at how to install. This document tells something like that.

```
Download the latest epel-release rpm from
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/

Install epel-release rpm:
# rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm

Install jack-audio-connection-kit rpm package:
# yum install jack-audio-connection-kit
```

I couldn't understand how to install all packages because this [link](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/) is just a link, not a RPM package.

**My Question**

jack-audio-connection-kit package is just an example. I want to install all packages at this link. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/ ... is a link to the EPEL downloads : a b c ... x y z . Click a letter to watch the packages. ... Why would you want to install all 11,990 EPEL packages ? ( Eleven thousand nine hundred and ninety ) ... `yum list all | grep epel` will show the EPEL package list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easy way - the YUM way. The hard and painfull way would be to solve dependencies manually.

If you'd searched for the epel-release RPM, you'd have find it in this path:

```
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
```

When you import it with the rpm -Uvh as adviced, it'd create the EPEL repo file in your /etc/yum.repos.d directory. It should be enabled by default, however you can check. Then all the content of EPEL 7 repository is available (including required jack-audio-connection-kit* packages).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the epel-release with yum.

> yum install epel-release